# SharePoint 2013 Workflow with many variables

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, lookup-column

I got stuck with the problem of lookup workflow. I need to fill the SharePoint list based on the 2 variables introduced earlier to another list. After some searching lookup workflow seems to be the best option. The problem is that one of my variable is number and is in the column number but the other one is the name of the header. I mean I got sth like this :

[image]

I have never used SharePoint Designer before and right now I found the lookup workflow for just the problem with numbers. Is it possible to get the searched values on the basis I mentioned ?

Thanks in advance for any help and patience.

Comment: Let's call the list on the left "List1" and on the right "List2." You want to set either column xyz OR column yxz depending on the value of "Name" from "List1" where 1[Number from List1] = [Number from List1]1? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the column is set by the name from List1 and the particular value from that column by the number from List1.

Answer (score 0):

First get the value of the "Name" column where `[List1:Number] equals [List2:Number]`. Then write an `if` statement to figure out which column to set.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it. Do I understand correctly that there is no concept like looping over columns headers and checking whether the particular one is right ? And I need to write exactly the number of if-statements that equals the number of elements that are compared ?

Comment: You're correct, there are no for or while loops in Designer, and no way to dynamically select a column to update.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This works fine but I thought about using javascript in order to obtain the same result. Is this possible in SP ? And if so where to start from ?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, though I don't know where you'd want to put the javascript. Perhaps in the List 2 create form? JQuery and SPServices would be a good starting point. You'd have to use the GetListItems operation with a CAML query to look up your values, then the Update command to add the values to list 2. But honestly, I wouldn't do it this way unless I had more than 10 columns to populate.

Comment: Ok thanks once again. I will give this a try as the values searched will be used for another search.In case of problems I will look for help here. Once again, thank you and Happy Easter!

Comment: Ok, I got my JS form where I would like to put values and based on it get data from existing list.  But I am not really sure where and how to add it ?

Comment: When do you want it to run or be viewed?

Comment: I want to use my JS form as a new list item form. Some values will be introduced by the user. The rest should be find (based on the introduced values) and the form should give me an item. This will work similarly to the form that can be done InfoPath. I know I should get my code into newly created form that I would set as defualt when creating new item. 
Actually my form works but I don't know how to set the vaules from my form into list (something like button submit ? ).

Comment: You'll need to add your form html and javascript to wherever you want the form to be. Then you'll need to lookup searched values and then commit all of the values to your list. I would user JQuery and SPServices. You could use JSON. There are a lot of examples online of how to get and commit code from/to SharePoint lists.